# MySQL calculate the difference of two columns into a Total column

Tags: mysql, sql, calculated-columns

```
Name  |InitialScore  | CurrentScore   | Total
 ----------------------------------------------- 
Bart  | 145          | 95             | -50 
Homer | 230          | 260            |  30 
Lisa  | 111          | 179            |  68
```

I have a table with the values above, what im trying to do is have the Total column find the difference between the initical score and the current Score from the table named mods.

i have tried multiple variations of this:

```
    ALTER TABLE mods
    ADD Total AS tphs + won PERSISTED
```

but i keep getting a "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;" My current MySQL is 5.1.70. Is there a way to accomplish a persisted column labeled Total so when i make changes to the CurrentScore column it automatically updates the total?

Comment: Specify the column type?

Comment: isn't total a computed column , and if I remember correctly, you remove computed columns when doing normalization itself

Comment: currently is not computed i wanna compute it but i dont know how...

Answer (score 0):

You want to use triggers. A trigger is a named database object that is associated with a table, and that activates when a particular event occurs for the table. This event can be an insert, update, or delete.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html

In this case, you want to setup a trigger before the insert.

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_total BEFORE INSERT ON mods
FOR EACH ROW SET Total = NEW.InitialScore + NEW.CurrentScore;
```

This will add `InitialScore` and `TotalScore` together and put it in the `Total` record. FYI: This trigger will work for both `INSERT` and `LOAD DATA`.

Answer (score 0):

```
update MYTABLE set Total = CurrentScore - InitialScore where 1=1
```

**It will update all the rows and if you want to update some specific rows than update the `where` clause accordingly.**

But if you want it to update automatically then use **Triggers** .